# Hibernate partially fill objects

Tags: sql, hibernate

I have a model with a lot of properties and I need to create a simple table with only a few of those properties.

Let's say I have a model defined as

```
@Entity
public class SomeData implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String code;
    private String someOtherCode;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String someOtherOtherCode;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<SomeOtherData> someOtherData;
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
    private LocalDate dateFrom;
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
    private LocalDate dateTo;
    //getters and setters
}
```

I can easily fetch a list of completely filled model objects with `Query query = entityManager.createQuery("from SomeData");`

Getting only `name`, `address` and `code`  with `Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select c.name, c.code, c.address from SomeData c");` seems to work differently. Instead of creating SomeData objects and filling them with partial data, what is recieved with `query.getResultList()` instead is a list of `Object` arrays representing rows.

Is there any way to tell Hibernate to give me a list of SomeData objects only filled with the data I asked for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this HQL:

```
SELECT new SomeData(c.name, c.code, c.address) FROM SomeData c
```

*Please keep in mind, that you have to use an existing constructor for this.*

The result will be a list of SomeData.

Comment: That does the trick. Thanks! One more quick question. Is that a good way of doing things? I can't modify the data models or create additional models just to fill a table, so I'm assuming this would take up less time and memory. Is my assumption correct or should I look for some other way to optimize?

Comment: There are other ways to do it as well. You could split up your table, and list only the necessary data. I think it would be better in this case, but it's not an option sometimes. If you can't do that, it still remains a good way if you need to fill your model partially.